# Angular 1.5.0 routing Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

For some reason I cannot get routing working using 1.5.0.  This works with angular 1.4.9.

```
.config([
    "$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/:stepNumber", {
                templateUrl: function (urlattr) {
                    return "/views/" + urlattr.stepNumber + ".html";
                }
            })
            .otherwise({
                //Redirect to first step if unknown
                redirectTo: "/1"
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
       }

])
```

The redirect doesn't seem to be happening.  Replacing all angular references from 1.5.0 back to 1.4.9 makes everything work as normal.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Nope - The console doesn't even have a warning